Unable to display Devanagari ligatures correctly in python tkinter
I am trying to display Devanagari (Hindi) text in python3 tkinter. I find that the display of text is incorrect in tkinter for all the widgets capable of holding text. The problem remains for any Truetype font with Unicode support. I have tried "Noto Sans", "Gargi", "Sankrit 2003" and some more Devanagari fonts.
This does not seem to be a problem with the font because -
i) I am getting correct display with any of the above fonts on ubuntu terminal (image attached)
ii) The text display is correct in html
iii) The problem appeared in python Fpdf. But it got resolved when the flag set_text_shaping was set to TRUE.
The code is as under :
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height = 5, width = 52)
T.config(font =("Gargi", 20))
l = Label(root, text = "Errors in Devanagari display")
l.config(font =("Gargi", 20))
l.pack()
T.pack()
T.insert(END, "   संधिस्थापनके प्रयत्नका औचित्य बताना..")
root.mainloop()

I have attached images of correct display as well as erroneous display.
Any help towards resolving the issue would be thankfully received. If this has already been addressed / discussed in this forum, a link to that topic may please be provided.
Thanks in advance.
Correct display
Incorrect display as seen in tkinter

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What platform, and what versions of Python and Tk are you using?  (Add print(TkVersion) to your code to get the latter.). I'm getting the correct output on my Mac, with Python 3.11, Tk 8.6.

I am using python 3.10 on ubuntu 22.04.  Tk version is 8.6

I have upgraded Python to version 3.11. The problem persists.

It worked for me using Python 3.12.7. Here is image: https://ibb.co/1Zw3Wnq

First, check what the actual font of your text is. Is "Gargi" in font.families()?

On macOS and windows Tk seems to use system level rendering. Rendering it is using on Linux doesn't appear to have opentype support, so the opentype features so opentype features in font are not being rendered.

@8349697  - The font "Gargi" is in listed in font families. The text is a transliterated ITRANS Roman text into unicode Devanagari (Hindi). This text has been successfully used to create pdf through python Fpdf. "gargi" font is a TrueType font.

On Windows, it looks similar to correct display (even without special fonts). The problem with text rendering exists on Linux Mint (even if I choose Devanagari fonts). It displays glyphs on the screen in the same order as the Unicode codepoints in the string. I believe this issue goes beyond tkinter and Python (most likely, X11). If your application's target audience is Linux users, consider other GUI libraries with Python wrappers/bindings.

@8349697  - I get your point. I concluded that the issue can not be resolved. I have switched over to Pyside6. In that package, I find that the display is correctly appearing.  Thank you for your efforts and insight. I am leaving the problem without identifying its root cause - Linux or Python or X11 or tkinter. Thanks again.
